# Security Certificate for Hazelcast ( A Proof certificate that claims that this software is free from any security vulnerability)

Tags: hazelcast

I need to use some opensource components/products for my project. Customer is adamant to get security certificate of these products before introducing these in to any such plan.
Could anyone help me to understand that, do these opensource products provide any sort of security certificate which claims that this product is free from any kind of security vulnerability?

A quick Answer is highly appreciated!!

Comment: Compare to corresponding closed-source/commercial products and see which 'security certificate' these provide. That discussion about open-source software security is old. Every known platform uses open-source software!

Answer (score 1):

Hazelcast is an open-source project and while the team is running various tests, including vulnerabilities tests, there is no formal guarantee/certification available. If you require a certification then you have 2 options:

1. Do the certification yourself. The code is open source after all.
2. Pay someone to do it for you. Hazelcast Enterprise is one option and it comes with similar guarantees.

Comment: Thanks kwart!! Looks ike we are in SYNC.I have also suggested a SAST Scan on this component for a reliability check.